# Formato de data perdido

Tags: java, datetime

Preciso montar uma condição para subtrair um dia da data, por exemplo criei uma coluna nova no banco de dados e preciso preencher ela, a condição para preencher ela é a seguinte, eu vou pegar a coluna `inicioPesagem` que me guarda data e hora, e vou verificar, se o horario dessa coluna `inicioPesagem` for menor que 06:00 a.m, ou seja antes das 06:00 preciso setar minha nova coluna um dia antes, pegar a data do `inicioPesagem`, subtrair um dia e setar, e se for maior que as 06:00 ou depois das 06:00 setar no mesmo dia.

Porém montei algumas condições para teste e ele não esta comparando, cai sempre no meu `else` ignorando as outras condições, eu creio q seja pela diferença de formato, a quem vem do banco vem no formato `2017-09-26 11:55:44.0` (nao sei da onde pego esse `.0` no final) e a que ta comparando vem nesse formato `Mon Oct 09 06:00:00 BRT 2017`, estou achando que é esse o problema, porém quando uso o `format` e depois do o `parse` para converter para data novamente, o meu formato é perdido.

Segue a classe criada para inserir os dados na coluna:

```
package metrix.model.database.util;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import metrix.model.entity.Pesagem;
import metrix.model.service.PesagemService;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

/**
 *
 * @author ricardo.campos
 */
public class InsereDataMed {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, Exception {

        List<Pesagem> pesagens = new ArrayList();

        HibernateUtil.openSession();

        pesagens = PesagemService.getAllPesos();

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat sdfh = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

        Date dataMed = new Date();

        Date dataFixa = sdfh.parse(sdf.format(new Date()) + " 06:00:00");

        HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();

        for (Pesagem p : pesagens) {

            int test = dataMed.compareTo(sdfh.parse(sdfh.format(dataFixa)));
            if (test == 0) {
                System.out.println("Igual");
            } else if (test > 0) {
                System.out.println("Depois");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Antes");
            }

            dataMed = p.getInicioPesagem();
            if (dataMed.before(dataFixa)) {
                DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(dataMed);
                dateTime = dateTime.plusDays(-1);
                p.setDataMed(dateTime.toDate());
            } else {
                p.setDataMed(p.getInicioPesagem());
            }
            PesagemService.salvar(p, HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession());
            System.out.println("Inicio Pesagem: " + p.getInicioPesagem()+"\n"+"Data Fixa: " + dataFixa+"\n"+"Data Med: "+dataMed+"\n");

        }

        HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
        HibernateUtil.closeCurrentSession();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu vi você está usando **dataFixa** + 6 horas só para fazer a comparação. Isso não é necessário na nova API de datas do Java 8, veja:

```
String dataMed = "2017-09-26 11:55:44.0"; // p.getInicioPesagem();
//String dataFixa = "Mon Oct 09 06:00:20 BRT 2017";

DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.0");
//DateTimeFormatter format2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");

LocalDateTime dataMed2 = LocalDateTime.parse(dataMed, format);
//LocalDateTime dataFixa2 = LocalDateTime.parse(dataFixa, format2);

// dataMed2.getHour() = 11    
if(dataMed2.getHour() < 6){
    System.out.println("Antes das 6 horas");
    dataMed = dataMed2.minusDays(1);
}
// Pra que o else se após as 6 não faz nada? Além disso você pega
// p.getInicioPesagem() de novo, entrando no else dataMed não foi
// alterado, logo a informação está redundante.

p.setDataMed(dataMed2.toLocalDate());
```

Deixei comentado caso queira usar a comparação de duas datas, ou a data venha no outro formato. Bastaria converter p.getInicioPesagem() para String.

Veja funcionando no [ideone](https://ideone.com/xFCGzQ).

Comment: Gustavo obrigado por querer ajudar, eu consegui resolver o problema, na vdd era um erro de lógica na comparação mesmo, não era p formato o problema,